# Convert IBM437 data into readable English text (UFT-8 or ASCII)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is sample code:

```
input = 'C:\\GOOD_AOA21_420031042_2016-02-09_02.38.11.txt'
file = File.open(input)
original_file_data = file.read
original_file_data_encoding = original_file_data.encoding
puts "String Encoding #{original_file_data_encoding}"
puts "#{original_file_data}"
#===============================================
ec = Encoding::Converter.new("IBM437", "UTF-8")
converted_to_utf_8 = ec.convert(s).dump
puts "Encoding after IBN 437 to UFT-8 conversion: #{converted_to_utf_8.encoding}"
puts "#{converted_to_utf_8}"
```

The output is:

```
String Encoding IBM437
 ���������@@�@@����������@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  Encoding after IBN 437 to UFT-8 conversion: UTF-8
"\u{2248}\u{b0}\u{2500}\u{2264}\u{b0}\u{2248}\u{2248}\u{2219}\u{2261}@@\u{251c}@@\u{2261}\u{2320}\u{2265}\u{2261}\u{2261}\u{2264}\u{b1}\u{2261}\u{2320}\u{2265}@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I am not sure why I am getting

```
"\u{2248}\u{b0}\u{2500}\u{2264}\...
```

and how to convert it to readable English.

Comment: It's impossible to know without having access to the original data.

Comment: hey Jordan, the first string in output - is original data, its not all but that how it looks like..if that helps...

Comment: What you show as the original data doesn't look like anything usable.